# LINQ to DataTable Join Query using OR condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have two DataTables with different data,common columns in both are quantity and Itemcode. I want to join the two tables together where two fields, (DataTable1.itemcode=DataTable2.itemcode) AND (DataTable1.quantity=DataTable2.quantity) OR ((DataTable1.quantity+1)=DataTable2.quantity) OR ((DataTable1.quantity+2)=DataTable2.quantity) . How would I write this in LINQ?

if item code is same and quantity is equal,exceeds by 1 or 2 then I should get joined result.

I tried using anonymous objects but that is for AND condition and OR condition was not fulfilled,so only itemcode and any one of these conditions was achieved at a time?
Please suggest me the correct way to do it?

Comment: Put the first condition in the join and the second group of conditions in the where section of the Linq query.

Comment: Thanks and I will upvote after trying. :D

Comment: Have you checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the following syntax to access fields of the dataset:

```
[DataTable Name].Field<string>(indexNo or ColumnName)
```

So you can write the following linq to put a join between two data tables:

```
from t1 in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
//join between two tables
join t2 in dataTable2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<string>(0) equals t2.Field<string>(0)
//where conditions
where t1.Field<string>(0) == [value]
//select clause
select t1.Field<string>(colmNo)
```

Also you can convert the two data tables to IEnumerable by creating extension method.